# map objects of two tables with keys

Tags: angular, typescript, linq

I have two objects that I get from an API.

```
user = {
    userTypeId: 1
    userType: null
}
userTypes = {
    {id:1, type:'admin}
}
```

I'm guessing that in my first call to the API to get the user I should call the API again to get the type

```
    let user;
    this.dataService.GetUser().subscribe(rps => {
        user = rps;
        this.dataService.GetUserType(rps.id).subscribe(userTypeRsp =>
        user.userType = userTypeRsp ////////////this is where I'm not sure what to do
        });
    });
```

But how could map the relationship between objects so userType is not null? I want to do something like in `C#` with `Linq`

```
user.userType = userTypeRsp.Where(x => x.id = user.userTypeId)
```

or something similar to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `Where` is `.find` or `.filter`. Since you're looking for a single item, you want `.find`

Example (this assumes `usertTypeResp` is an `Array`):

```
user.userType = userTypeRsp.find(x => x.id = user.userTypeId)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find